# Handling multiple values in subquery

Tags: sql

I have two tables one of which holds employee information and the other that holds dependents information.  I want to create a query which retrieves all the first names of each employees children and combine them into one field of the results.

I know how to create a subquery that returns a single result as a field in another query but not having any luck figuring this one out. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Tables: tblPersonnel, tblFamilyData linked by [ID] primary [sponsorID] foriegn

Desired output:

```
EmployeeName | Address | KidName1, KidName2, KidName3
```

Comment: can we have some more information about the context pleasE? what SQLangauges are you using, what DB engine, what scripting language/DBGUI ? etc etc etc

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

```
select EmployeeName,Address,(select STUFF((select ',' + firstname+ '' from tblFamilyData ts 
    where a.ID=ts.SponsorID for xml path(''), type).value('.', 'varchar(max)'), 1, 1, '')) as KidName from tblPersonnel a
```

This query selects name and address from one table,then using first table id i m fetching data from second table and using xml to concatenate the values.

Comment: Can you provide explanation to your answer?

Comment: @Christian Mark,It selects name and address from one table,then using first table id i m fetching data from second table and using xml to concatenate the values..

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT EmployeeName, Address,
(Select KidName + ',' 
 From tblFamilyData K
 Where K.EmployeeID = P.EmployeeID
 For XML PATH ('')) AS kids
FROM tblPersonnel P
```

I am not sure what your exact columns are, beacuse you didn't specified the complete schema, but this is the concept..

Comment: Please note that I've added the - For XML PATH ('')

Answer (score -1):

```
Select tblPersonnel.EmployeeName, tblPersonnel.Address, tblFamilyData.KidName from tblPersonnel, tblFamilyData where tblPersonnel.ID = tblFamilyData.sponsorID;
```

Comment: This will return multiple rows,but he wants in one row seperated by comma